# Using custom fonts without install win8.1 WPF APP

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fonts

My WPF win APP is using following code and it works alright when font is already installed.

```
Button infoButton = new Button();
infoButton.Content = new FontIcon
{
    FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe MDL2 Assets"),
    Glyph = "&#xE946;",
    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.WhiteSmoke)
};
```

I want to use custom font without installing it on windows. I've included all relevant font files within my solution (build action set as content). How can I use that with above code? I know how to use it in XAML but I'm want to do it in C#.

Comment: Cannot you add it to resource and from there set the font?

Comment: I've to do this from server code

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below link to use new Font in the WPF application which is not installed in the system - It worked:

<http://www.bizicbojan.com/post/2011/01/19/Embedding-and-Referencing-Fonts-in-your-WPF-application.aspx>

I have used FontFamily in the control as below.

```
FontFamily="/HPID.KioskUIControls;component/Fonts/#Segoe MDL2 Assets".
```

The font file is available in Fonts folder for me.

May be this will help you too.

Thanks.

Comment: that's XAML based again

Comment: Yes, that was from XAML. May be this helps. I didn't try it.

Comment: http://www.alteridem.net/2014/02/24/custom-fonts-in-wpf-applications/  --- Try this link.